# Running a python script from command prompt

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, command-line

I'm working on a tutorial for a big data class and am having trouble in the command line (Windows 7 Pro).  I'm not very familiar with the command line environment so this is probably something simple, but here goes:

I have a python script called `mapper.py` that is stored in the directory

```
E:\Documents\School\Math\M 461\MapReduce\PythonScripts
```

and a file named

```
Medicare_Provider_Util_Payment_PUF_CY2013.txt
```

that is stored in

```
E:\Documents\School\Math\M 461\MapReduce\Data
```

Python (Anaconda) is installed at `C:\Program Files\Anaconda3`.  I'm trying to feed the file to the script and execute it from the command line using

```
type Medicare_Provider_Util_Payment_PUF_CY2013.txt
| 'C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python' mapper.py
```

I use the apostrophes because otherwise it doesn't like the space in Program Files.  However, when I execute this command it says that "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."  I'm not sure where to go from here so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have python installed, you should run `python3 mapper.py`

Comment: if you have no issue putting the whole path for the files into the command prompt I'd recommend you try that.

Answer (score 0):

The text file and the Python file aren't in the same directory, so your example can't work.  Try this series of commands in at your command prompt:

First, make the common parent the current directory

```
E:
cd E:\Documents\School\Math\M 461\MapReduce
```

Then run your script, giving the path to the data and python files:

```
type Data\Medicare_Provider_Util_Payment_PUF_CY2013.txt | 'C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python' PythonScripts\mapper.py
```